# MathJax rendering for suggested edit queue

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, diff, mathjax

I would like to suggest a new feature that when reviewing suggested edits on sites that support MathJax that the suggested edit queue renders the MathJax in the rendered output view. The following suggested edit on Electrical Engineering is an example:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25219

Personally I find that verifying the edit is valid is difficult when that view doesn't render the MathJax. I've been in the habit of opening a new window to paste the markup into a new question (that I discard) to view the rendered output, but it doesn't make for a very efficient workflow.

Comment: And more generally in all edit diffs.

Comment: Given how many times I've done MathJax edits on math.stackexchange, I kinda wonder if they already have it, unless the guys over there also have the patience to do what you've been doing.

Comment: How would we highlight it though?

Comment: `s/LaTeX/MathJax/g`

Comment: @Sean thanks good idea, when I originally posted I didn't understand the differences.

Comment: @PeterJ :) no worries

Comment: I'm going to shamelessly bump this request. It's still hard to review those edits, I don't think anything changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a very good idea. However, I can imagine this could be quite time-consuming from a programmer's point of view. Look for example at revision 2 [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/129572/revisions). The LaTeX is not completely new according to the highlighting software, there are parts that are not made green, so simply running MathJax over the output of the highlighting software wouldn't be sufficient (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232124/205264) also).

**But**, what would be easily possible if I'm not mistaken, is to **make a button in the suggested edit review queue to view the new post**.

Now, it's only possible to view the rendered output difference or markdown difference. Adding a third option to view the rendered output of the post after editing would solve this issue and could also be helpful in other cases, when all the highlighting makes the difference view a little confusing.

[Another option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232125/205264), but probably more time-consuming, would be to let the highlighting software see MathJax parts as blocks. Either the block existed before, or it didn't. If it existed in the old post, nothing has to be highlighted. If it didn't exist in the old post, the whole block is assumed new.

Comment: That's a good idea on the seperate button, often for more complex equations it's handy to have them in a new browser window regardless.